# Custom CheckBox control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, checkbox

I need to create a custom checkBox control. So far I have:

[image]

So at the root instead of having UserControl or Window I have Checkbox. (On my code behind I inherit from CheckBox in order for this to work)

When I make that change I get the box that I highlighted on the first image. I do not want to have that box.

Also I will like to overide the functionality of the checkbox control. I will like for it to be checked when I click on the image that shows the 0 or 1. Right now if I click outside the image on the shade of the square for example I will fire the Cheked event. How can I overide that functionality? I already have my own animations that trigger when the mouse enters the number image and also when the mouse is down etc.

### Edit

The reason why I avoided having visual states is because I need to fire events when the mouse enters a spesific image not any part of the control. In other words when using the visual states and I applied a style for the mouse over event that event fired if I placed my mouse anywhere inside the usercontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<CheckBox x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyCustomCheckBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <CheckBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
             <TextBlock>Whatever</TextBlock>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </CheckBox.Template>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: +1 thanks a lot for the help. when I place the root grid instead of textbox I got an error. `"Cannot find a FrameworkElement with Name 'image1'."` I will investigate further on the error and provide more detail.

Comment: Found the error. The only problem that I have now is that I had to remove the storiboards and triggers...

Comment: source property of the image should be something like: "/WpfApplication1;component/Images/image1.png" where "Images" is a solution folder within WpfApplication1 solution.

Comment: That was one of the 15 errors. For some reason the storyboards will not work if I place everything inside controlTemplate. I will just use a UserControl instead...

Comment: you can place storyboards outside the template, right after </CheckBox.Template>